# Issue In pulling the data from AccessDB

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I am trying to pull the data from access db and populate, with the following code

```
    String[] tableColumnsName = {"col 1","col 2","col 3"}; 
    DefaultTableModel aModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
    aModel.setColumnIdentifiers(tableColumnsName);
    try {
        // the query
        rs = db.query("SELECT * FROM Students ");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegisterGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    // Loop through the ResultSet and transfer in the Model
    java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
    try {
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegisterGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    try {
        while(rs.next()){
        Object[] objects = new Object[10];
        // tanks to umit ozkan for the bug fix!
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        objects[i]=rs.getObject(i+1);
        }
        aModel.addRow(objects);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegisterGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    jTable2.setModel(aModel);
}//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed
```

I am able to pull the data from one. How can I pull it from another table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a lot of assumptions about your data, and leaving your resources open after you've finished with them.

First, you should use `ResultSetMetaData` to build the `TableModel` column information, then you should use it to build the row data from the `ResultSet`, for example...

```
DefaultTableModel aModel = new DefaultTableModel();
try (ResultSet rs = db.query("SELECT * FROM Students ")) {
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    for (int col = 0; col < rsmd.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        aModel.addColumn(rsmd.getColumnName(col + 1));
    }

    while (rs.next()) {
        Object[] value = new Object[rsmd.getColumnCount()];
        for (int col = 0; col < rsmd.getColumnCount(); col++) {
            value[col] = rs.getObject(col + 1);
        }
        aModel.addRow(value);
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(RegisterGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
jTable2.setModel(model);
```

Now, I'd build a utility method which could take your query (or table name) and return a `TableModel`

Comment: I am getting an error java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid descriptor index